# How to convert Html files to Pdf?

Tags: pdf, html

The title say it all, I want a 100% accurate tool to convert a HTML page to a PDF document.

Comment: Through which rendering engine?

Comment: Don't we all...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check out [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/). It uses the Webkit layout engine (as used in Safari, Chrome, etc.).

Comment: +1 good answer, wkhtml even waits until jscript code is done with the dom (nice for asciidoc-toc stuff)

Comment: I've been using NitroPDF for a couple years.  Just found wkhtmltopdf, it works better, is faster and runs on ubuntu.

Comment: This didn't work for me on OS X. It would never finish 'rendering'. A very similar program did work, called [wkpdf](http://plessl.github.com/wkpdf/)

Comment: Been looking for something like this for a number of hours now - thank you!

Comment: i use it in ubuntu . works great but somt pictures are not in the output. my not perfect workaround: `cutycapt --url=https://stackoverflow.com/cv/sl5net --out=traditional_sl5net.jpg --print-backgrounds=on && img2pdf traditional_sl5net.jpg -o traditional_view.pdf`

Answer (score 6):

Consider the fact that no two browsers can render that HTML completely identically for a moment, and then realize that you're never going to get it.

Comment: Well, if you interpret "100% accurate" to mean "exactly as rendered in a specific browser", then you can most definitely get that.

Comment: @Michael: Sure, but that information wasn't included in the question.

Answer (score 4):

- Install a [virtual printer driver](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_virtual_printer_software) that saves print output as PDF
- Open HTML in browser
- Printo to virtual printer

Comment: nice workaround, I'll try it

Comment: Be aware that depending on the browser you're using, the settings in it, and the webpage, some parts of the printed PDF page won't be 100% what you see on screen. Obvious things to look for, if you have a dark/black background set with light/white text over it, default print settings in most browsers will change that to black text with white background.

Comment: Yes, this won't be 100% accurate, results will vary from page to page.

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt: AFAIK, virtual printers do not [fully support HTML links](http://www.novapdf.com/kb/create-active-pdf-links-using-novapdf-professional-68.html), right?

Answer (score 0):

I use [Primo PDF](http://www.primopdf.com/index.aspx) to convert HTML to PDF. it's just a PDF Printer.

`File` > `Print` > Choose primo PDF

[image]

It's useful one for me because I couldn't use the Internet everything. If I want to read some articles from Wiki, I've printed out with that printer and read at home.

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking for this too. My best solution at the moment is to use a combination of Firefox and [PDFCreator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfcreator/). I've also tried the other main browsers, but they don't let you turn off their own headers and footers. If you want to be able to print grey/gray text as grey (rather than black) then be sure to enable the "Print Background (color and images)" option in the File | Page Setup | Format & Options dialog.

Unfortunately, none of the main browsers seem to support the CSS @page rule for specifying things like headers, footers, widows, orphans, page sizes, landscape/portrait, etc.

There is a tool called [Prince](http://www.princexml.com/) that claims to be able to do all of that (and more), with good reviews, but I haven't used it because it's expensive. (There is a free version for personal use, but it adds its own logo onto the front page of the PDF document.)

Answer (score 0):

[wkpdf](http://plessl.github.com/wkpdf/) worked perfectly for me when wkhtmltopdf did not, on OS X. It's a Ruby Gem, which was very simple to use on a stock OS X install.

Answer (score 0):

if you use [Ubunto](https://ubuntu.com).

today i using [img2pdf](https://github.com/josch/img2pdf):

```
sudo apt-get install -y cutycapt
sudo apt-get install -y img2pdf
cutycapt --url=https://stackoverflow.com/story/sl5net --out=story_sl5net.jpg --print-backgrounds=on && img2pdf story_sl5net.jpg -o story_sl5net.pdf
```

my problem is that no automatic page breaks are created when converting

for OCR i using https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Paperwork/

Maybe also very helpful way to do this:

https://github.com/Szpadel/chrome-headless-render-pdf